# using index.php to make 404 page show up instead

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a hosted wordpress site.

I don't like the idea of people accessing my wp-content folder, so I have added in the blank index.php in there.

But I am not satisfied with this solution. To go a step further, is it possible for me to rewrite this index.php such that it does not just show a blank page, I want it to show a 404 page which I already have created. What code should I put in there?

Comment: you could have tried with index.html if you wish

Comment: If you have access to edit the .htaccess file you can Disable Indexing using the following line.

Options -Indexes

http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml more info (and source)

Comment: I can't really use index.html, because wordpress uses index.php. Thanks later on i tried disabling browsing of directory i.e. Options-Indexes, I realised its more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could put this in your index.php

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, in the end this is what I did, I added

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /
```

to my .htaccess file

so when someone tries to access my plugin folder for eg. mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/abc-plugin , my 404 page appears. However when I go to mysite.com/wp-content or mysite.com/wp-content/plugins, a blank page still shows up.

But I guess its better than nothing, because when I first attempted using only

```
 Options -Indexes
```

in my .htaccess, and I tried to access the plugin folder for eg. mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/abc-plugin , a 403 page with my hosting logo shows up, which I found it unsightly.

Comment: update* found out that the blank page shows up because I had a blank index.php  in those folders